# Retrieve information from Table Cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with 2 labels and a button. The cell has it's own class:

```
class personTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func inviteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }   
}
```

Inside the view controller that contains the table view, I add the cells to the table in this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "person", for: indexPath) as? personTableCell
        cell?.nameLabel.text = results[indexPath.row].name
        cell?.emailLabel.text = results[indexPath.row].email
        return cell!
}
```

When a user presses the button inside the cell that calls the `@IBAction func inviteButtonPressed`, I want to add the cell's labels' text into an array that's initialized in the same view controller as the table.

How can I achieve such a thing if the `@IBAction func inviteButtonPressed` is in a seperate file as the table's view controller?

Comment: Not related: Too many question and exclamation marks for the birds. Seriously: Never get information from the table view cell (the view), get it from the datasource array (the model)

Comment: @vadian elaborate please?

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:indexPath)` returns non-optional cell. It's pretty silly to optional down cast it. The cell is obviously created in Interface Builder so you know it does exist.

Comment: So you recommend to use `as!` instead of `as?` ?

Comment: Yes, and to remove all following `?` and `!`

Comment: Ok, got it. Good to know as someone relatively new to swift. Also working on trying to get information out of the array I populate the cells with instead of the cells themselves, not really sure how to though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using delegate is one of solutions.

In TableViewCell class

```
@objc protocol PersonTableViewCellDelegate {
    func personTableViewCellInviteButtonPressed(cell: PersonTableViewCell)
}

class PersonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: PersonTableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func inviteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.personTableViewCellInviteButtonPressed(cell: self)
    }

}
```

In ViewController class

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, PersonTableViewCellDelegate {

    var results: [Person] = []
    var invited: [Person] = []

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "person", for: indexPath) as! PersonTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = results[indexPath.row].name
        cell.emailLabel.text = results[indexPath.row].email
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func personTableViewCellInviteButtonPressed(cell: PersonTableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        let person = results[indexPath.row]
        invited.append(person)
    }

}
```